# How to write unit test for CakePHP: Model->find()

Tags: cakephp-2.0, phpunit

I have I have a method that uses model->find(). As I understood to write the test, I must use mock. I'm new to writing tests.  can you tell me which way to search.

```
function findSomethingInDB($client_id, $expiredLag): array
{
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() - $expiredLag);
    $conditions = [
        "DB.expires >" => $date,
        'client_id' => $client_id,
        'state' => 0,
    ];

    $result = $this->find('all', [
        'recursive' => -1,
        'conditions' => $conditions,
    ]);
    return $result;
}
```

Here my code in php unit test. I tried to write myself but the hike is not right.

```
public function testFindSomethingInDB()
{
    $client_id = '1';
    $expireLag = '0';

    $expected = [
        '0' => [
            'DB' => [
                'id' => '3068',
                'procedure_id' => '1',
                'client_id' => '1',
                'object' => 'test',
                'date' => '2034-02-09 22:05:37',
                'entity' => 'test',
                'freshness' => '-354923520',
                'expires' => '2022-11-12 00:13:37',
            ],
        ],
    ];

    $mysql = $this->getMockBuilder(ErrorK50::class)
                  ->getMock();
    $mysql->expects($this->any())
          ->method('findSomethingInDB')
          ->with($this->equalTo($client_id), $this->equalTo($expireLag))
          ->will($this->returnValue($expected));
    $errorK50 = new ErrorK50($mysql);
    $result = $errorK50->findSomethingInDB($client_id, $expireLag);

    $this->assertEquals($expected, $result);
}
```

The project uses phpunit test 6.5.9

Comment: What are you trying to test? it's not clear. What is the function `findErrorInDB()` ? is that function calling `findSomethingInDB()` ?

Comment: findSomethingInDB callaing method find

Answer (score 0):

In your `findSomethingInDB()` implementation I can see that you are calling the function `find()` in the same class - `$this->find(...)` - I'm not sure why you are injecting the mock to it's original class.

To achieve what you need to do is to partially mock ErrorK50. Basically, when creating the mock, you specify which functions will be mocked and which have to behave normally, using the `setMethods(['array','of','functions'])` function.

```
$errorK50PartialMock = $this->getMockBuilder(ErrorK50::class)
     ->setMethods(['find'])
     ->getMock();

$errorK50PartialMock->expects($this->once())
     ->method('find')
     ->willReturn($expected);

$result = $errorK50PartialMock->findErrorInDB($client_id, $expireLag);

$this->assertEquals($expected, $result);
```